# HMAC signing of response

Tags: api, http, hmac

I'm implementing HMAC hashing of incoming messages to my REST Api. The HMAC hash is set in the Authorization header of the request in the form: Authorization: [Scheme] [Hash]

I also want to sign the response. What header is most suitable to place the response hash in?

Comment: Do you want to sign the response body or the complete response (body and headers)?

Comment: I'm signing both, that is, im computing the hash based on a concatination of some of the other headers + md5(content)

Comment: HMAC-signing a MD5 hash is no more secure than not using HMAC at all. You are vulnerable to extension attacks, where an attacker can modify the content and carefully add some bytes to yield the same MD5(content).

Comment: I'm computing the hmac hash of the concatination of the headers + the md5 content. http://www.wolfe.id.au/2012/10/20/what-is-hmac-and-why-is-it-useful/

Comment: Suppose that signature and relevant headers are left untouched and content is carefully forged. Same MD5(content) and same headers mean same HMAC signature in your scenario, but content has been tampered with.

Comment: Ok, so what do you suggest instead?

Comment: Well, you should be using TLS, which is made specifically for encrypting content and identifying source. The server is authenticated by its X.509 certificate, which cannot be forged easily (provided that you get it signed by a reputable CA, of course).

Comment: I could give my left hand for SSL. Unfortunately it's not possible (the client is a microcontroller) and the SSL library has some really serious bugs which makes the whole device unpredictable.